# SQL Server 2005 Query

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I just can't get my head around this today - so your help is much appreciated.

**Table Structure**

```
Create Table #trans
(
TransactionId int,
AccountNumber varchar(10),
TransactionAmount money,
TransactionDate DateTime
)

Create Table #payments
(
PaymentId int,
AccountNumber varchar(10),
PaymentAmount money,
PaymentDate
)
```

**Example Data**

```
Insert Into #trans
Values ( 500500 ,'10000001', 10000.00, '2008-10-02')
GO
Insert Into #trans
Values ( 500501 ,'10000001', 10000.00, '2008-10-02')
GO
Insert Into #trans
Values ( 500502 ,'10000001', 10000.00, '2008-10-02')
GO

Insert Into #payments
Values ( 0001,'10000001', 10000.00, '2008-10-02')
GO
Insert Into #payments
Values ( 0002,'10000001', 10000.00, '2008-10-02')
GO
Insert Into #payments
Values ( 0003,'10000001', 10000.00, '2008-10-02')
GO
```

**Expected Results**

I need to be able to match the transactions with the payments.  So basically I will get:

```
TransactionId     PaymentId 

500500           0001 
500501           0002 
500502           0003
```

The transaction being matched on the account number, date of payment and amount.

It seems really simple but I just cant seem to work it out.

**Update**

To try to clarify my situation, I have a list of historical transactions as per the above table. I have file containing payments, again historical. I need to match the transactions to the payments within the file.

Why?

- to find any transactions that don't exist in the file.
- to find any payments within the file that don't have a corresponding transaction
- to create a "link" table that will contain the TransactionID and PaymentID so that in future anyone else querying this data won't have the same issue.

Comment: When there's a account / amount / date clash, as there is here, what determines which transaction matches which payment? database ID?

Comment: @rup - it doesn't really matter which paymentid gets mapped to which transactionid.  Just as long as they only get mapped once and there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you can't work it out is because there is nothing that relates a Transaction to a Payment.

You would need to add a foreign key to either one of the tables that references the related piece of information in the other table for the result to have any meaning.

I would modify the tables like:

```
Create Table #payments
(
    PaymentId int,
    AccountNumber varchar(10),
    PaymentAmount money,
    PaymentDate,
    TransactionId int,
    foreign key (TransactionId) references #trans(TransactionId)
)

Create Table #trans
(
    TransactionId int,
    AccountNumber varchar(10),
    TransactionAmount money,
    TransactionDate DateTime
)
```

And then you can do a simple query (or a join if you want more than just the ids):

```
select TransactionId, PaymentId from #payments
```

Comment: I'd put the key in the other direction, so that a payment is a type of transaction.

Comment: @Joel - That's actually what I wanted to do so it could support multiple payments as part of a single transaction. Apparently my hands didn't do what my head was thinking. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I can see where you are coming from and this is where I want to get to. However, how am I going to do this. Any one of those payments could be linked any one of the transactions. I need to be able to create a one to one mapping so I can create the FK. It doesn't really matter which payment id gets mapped to as long as a transaction Id or payment id is only mapped once.

Answer (score 3):

Why is payment a separate table?  A payment is just one type of transaction.  If there's extra data that goes with a payment, that's fine.  But even in that case, you shouldn't duplicate the basic transaction info in the payment table.  Put it in the transaction table and give the payment table a TransactionID column that you will use to relate it back to the transaction.

Comment: Here, here.  It may appear that you're denormalizing the structure but in actuality you're not.  Normalization hasn't come into play yet.

Comment: I need to match the transaction over an account to the physical payment. Hence the different tables.  I wish I didn't but I do!  I want to try to add in some FK Constraints to link the transaction to a payment.  The only other way I can think of - is to do match them on a row by row basis but that sounds like a massive hack to me.

Comment: @Barry - you're not hearing me.  When you receive a payment, you create a transaction for that payment that holds the account number, amount, and date.  You also create your payment record for the physical payment, but that table holds **none** of those things by itself. Instead it gets a TransactionID for where to look up that data.  It might also have additional data like a check number, but under no circumstance should you duplicate the transaction.

Comment: If this is a one-off match to fill in a FK then you might as well do it row-by-row, hack or not, assuming your datasets aren't colossal - the tradeoff runtime / cleanliness / efficiency vs development time is different for a one-off.